# Assigning id of old object to new object will insert it as duplicate @ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an unidirectional `@ManyToMany` relationship in my class, as follows:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {
        CascadeType.MERGE,
        CascadeType.PERSIST
})
@JoinTable(
        name=TABLE_NAME_JOB_JOB_TYPE,
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name=COLUMN_JOB_ID, referencedColumnName = COLUMN_JOB_ID),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name=COLUMN_JOB_TYPE_ID, referencedColumnName = COLUMN_JOB_TYPE_ID)
)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private Set<JobTypeModel> types;
```

I had a hard time updating the number of Job Types, a Job had, because of a simple mistake, which I finally found.
However, I can not tell why this happens.

Basically, what I did, was that I had a method which merged the old and the new Job, and instead of taking everything from newJob, and add to oldJob, I take the ID of oldJob, and assign it to newJob.

So, like this:

```
public JobModel mergeAndUpdate(JobModel oldJob, JobModel newJob) {
    getLoggerService().debug(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "mergeAndUpdate({oldJob}, {newJob})");
    //newJob.setId(oldJob.getId()); //If doing this, then it fails
    //Was trying to avoid doing this:
    oldJob.setX(newJob.getX());
    oldJob.setY(newJob.getY());
    oldJob.setZ(newJob.getZ());

    return getJobRepository().saveAndFlush(oldJob);
    //return getJobRepository().saveAndFlush(newJob);
}
```

My JobRepository is an interface that extends `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository`

When doing this, when attempting to persist an update (either with one added, or one removed jobType), it would fail.

When adding a new jobType, it would tell me that I have a duplicate entry in the association table JOB_JOB_TYPE.

```
Hibernate: insert into job_job_type (job_id, job_type_id) values (?, ?)
2017-11-26 00:02:28.202  WARN 74560 --- [p-nio-80-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
2017-11-26 00:02:28.202 ERROR 74560 --- [p-nio-80-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Duplicate entry '187-2' for key 'PRIMARY'
2017-11-26 00:02:28.203  INFO 74560 --- [p-nio-80-exec-6] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

When removing a jobType, from the Job set, and persisting the new Job, nothing would happen -> the relationship would still stay.

Does anybody know why?

Note:
Doing this, for objects that have no `@ManyToMany` relationship (aka. adding the ID of the old object to the new object, instead of adding everything else from the new object, to the old object, will attempt to update, when calling the `saveAndFlush` method.

I am using: 
MariaDB 10.1.28
Spring Boot 1.5.4 (with the associated spring boot starter data jpa)

Comment: Behavioral persistent for me is logically, you must first delete old record(with X id), to add new record with the same id. Maybe try save to field `Integer temp` id value, delete old record, and try add new with id from `temp`

Comment: That means two queries. The way I solved the issue uses just one query. I just want to know why the other way around is not working, and an explanation of what actually happens. And since I could find nowhere, this specific question, I thought it might help others, in this situation, as well.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is the DB is in charge. Let it create all IDs for you. Don't try to set IDs on objects. If you are inserting a NEW record, you can insert with null ID and the DB will assign the ID,and you won't know the ID until after the insert of course. But importantly, if you are persisting a record that HAS and ID on it (on the POJO object) then you need to be sure it's doing an 'update' operation not an 'insert' or you'll get this problem.

Comment: When calling 'saveAndFlush', it will do an update. So if I set an ID, it will do an update. If I get a record from the DB, map it to an object, the object will also contain an ID. If I change other stuff on the said object, and leave the ID intact, it's doing the update correctly. But here, we are talking about @ManyToMany relationship, and the update is happening in the parent table, but will not happen in the association table.

Comment: Lookup "cascading". If there isn't an obvious way to cascade you may have to do manual updates to both tables. I'm rusty on @ManyToMany but have done it before

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946938/jpa-manytomany-writing-on-create-but-not-update

and google this "updating with spring @manytomany" :P That search will get lots of hits.